# Remove zeroth index with array.splice in Javascript. (FCC Slasher Flick challenge)

Tags: javascript, arrays

For a Free Code Camp challenge I need to do the following:

> Return the remaining elements of an array after chopping off n elements from the head.
>   The head means the beginning of the array, or the zeroth index.

This is my solution:

```
function slasher(arr, howMany) {
    if (howMany === 0) {
        return arr;
    }

    if (howMany === 1) {
        arr = arr.splice(0, 1);
    }

    if (howMany > 1) {
        arr = arr.splice(0 + howMany, howMany);
    }

    return arr;
}

slasher([1, 2, 3], 2);
```

The code works for everything except when `howMany === 1`. 
I thought `array.splice(0,1)` would remove 1 entry from the zeroth index.

Comment: Two tips for one (wrongly formulated/formatted) question. Good way to start my day of coding! I've gone through your answer and the edit. Many thanks for the constructive criticism and elaborate answer.

Comment: Note closely that the question reads *return the **remaining elements** of an array after chopping*, not *return the array after chopping*, which are two different things. In general, splicing arrays is hard to understand, bug-prone, and not necessary. Instead, **transform** the array into a new one with the elements you want.

Answer (score 4):

> The code works for everything except...

No it doesn't. It returns the elements that were removed, because you're assigning the return value of [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to `arr`. The return value of `splice` is an array containing the elements that were removed. But the instruction was *"Return the remaining elements of an array after chopping off n elements from the head."*, which is a completely different thing. It *seemed* to work in your test case because of the specific test you did, but it doesn't work in the general case.

`slasher` is a one-liner, because it does what [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) does:

```
function slasher(arr, howMany) {
   return arr.slice(howMany);
}
```

Example with tests, including one test demonstrating a case that wouldn't work with your `splice` solution:

```js
function slasher(arr, howMany) {
   return arr.slice(howMany);
}
// Examples:
test([1, 2, 3], 0);
test([1, 2, 3], 1);
test([1, 2, 3], 2);
test([1, 2, 3], 3);
// Specific case that wouldn't work with the `splice` solution:
test([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2);
// The `splice` solution would result in `[3, 4]` instead of `[3, 4, 5]`

function test(arr, howMany) {
  console.log("Removing first " + howMany + " from [" + arr.join(",") + "]: [" + slasher(arr, howMany).join(",") + "]");
}
```

`slice` returns an array of the elements in the original array starting with the index you provide, which conveniently is exactly what `slasher` needs to do.

> I thought `array.splice(0,1)` would remove 1 entry from the zeroth index.

It does. And it returns an array containing the entry that was removed, which you're assigning to `arr` and then returning. That's not what the return value is meant to be.

Comment: `Return the remaining elements of an array after chopping off n elements from the head` Isn't that the end of the array after `howMany`?

Comment: @Xotic750: Yes. Which is what `slice` does, and not what the array `splice` returns is.

Comment: :) Sorry, the wording was making my head spin for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
function slasher(arr, howMany) {
  // it doesn't always pay to be first
  var output;
  if(howMany>=arr.length){
    output=[];
  }
  else{
  output=arr.slice(howMany,arr.length);

  }
  return output;
}
```